# Powershell How to determine what Windows Updates have not been superseded?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I'm building a Powershell script to download Windows updates to slipstream them into offline Windows images using DISM. For example, my list for a Windows 10 search looks like this.

```
d          Id       KB      Title                                                                                       Rating   
-          --       --      -----                                                                                       ------   
3/8/2016   MS16-036 3144756 Security Update for Adobe Flash Player                                                      Critical 
3/8/2016   MS16-035 3141780 Security Update for .NET Framework to Address Security Feature Bypass                       Important
3/8/2016   MS16-034 3143145 Security Update for Windows Kernel-Mode Drivers to Address Elevation of Privilege           Important
3/8/2016   MS16-033 3143142 Security Update for Windows USB Mass Storage Class Driver to Address Elevation of Privilege Important
3/8/2016   MS16-032 3143141 Security Update for Secondary Logon to Address Elevation of Privile                         Important
3/8/2016   MS16-030 3143136 Security Update for Windows OLE to Address Remote Code Execution                            Important
3/8/2016   MS16-028 3143081 Security Update for Microsoft Windows PDF Library to Address Remote Code Execution          Critical 
3/8/2016   MS16-027 3143146 Security Update for Windows Media to Address Remote Code Execution                          Critical 
3/8/2016   MS16-026 3143148 Security Update for Graphic Fonts to Address Remote Code Execution                          Critical 
3/8/2016   MS16-024 3142019 Cumulative Security Update for Microsoft Edge                                               Critical 
3/8/2016   MS16-023 3142015 Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer                                            Critical
```

What can I do to determine what updates that have not been superseded?

Comment: How are you getting even that much information?  That is, what API are you using?

Comment: I got it from scraping https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 with Powershell

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your circumstances and needs, running [a WSUS server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332157.aspx) may be one option.  You wouldn't actually need to use it to distribute updates, but [there's an API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744624(v=vs.85).aspx) you can use to query the WSUS server database.  You could also use the API to "approve" the updates you want, causing WSUS to download them.

My best guess is that this would be overkill for your scenario, and the approach you've suggested in your self-answer will work better.  But WSUS may be a more sensible option for some future readers, and it wont hurt for you to have an alternative to consider in case you run into trouble.

It should also be noted that the set of updates offered by Microsoft via WSUS are slightly different to those offered via Windows Update and/or updates may be released to the two channels at different times.  (Security updates are typically released to both channels simultaneously or nearly so.)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that neither my question nor my answer was programmatic in nature. An answer in programming would have satisfied my needs though so I felt it belonged in this category.

It turns out that in order to best determine the updates that an offline image needs is to use the [Download Microsoft Security Bulletin Data](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245778) link found on https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/. The best bet is to query the Excel file with a program and then determine what updates supersede others. From there, about downloading the actual MSU files that are usable from DISM I'm not sure. However this answers my question well enough and I'll have to do some internet sleuthing to find out how to download a list of MSU files in batch.